# uuid as keyword argument <pk> in django urls.py

Tags: django, uuid

I am using a uuid4 as id in some django models. Thats why I cannot use `<int:pk>` in the `urls.py` because it wont match. Is there another prefix I can use to match these uuids like `a2182835-4518-cb95-8eaf-0d5a34105cb2` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [uuid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) path converter instead of int. From the docs

> uuid - Matches a formatted UUID. To prevent multiple URLs from mapping to the same page, dashes must be included and letters must be lowercase. For example, 075194d3-6885-417e-a8a8-6c931e272f00. Returns a UUID instance.

So for your purposes changing `<int:pk>` to `<uuid:pk>` should do the trick

Comment: @Foobar you haven't given much to go off of, but this was added in Django 2.0 so perhaps you are using an older version?Otherwise it sounds like you must have implemented it incorreclty

Comment: I solved this by declaring lookup_field = 'uuid' in my ViewSet. I didn't make any other changes.